# What is wrong? Incomplete type is not allowed?

Tags: c++

I don't understand what is wrong with this code. It says "incomplete type is not allowed for my function."

This is what I'm trying to do:

> Write a function named `yrClac()` that has an integer parameter representing the total number of days since the turn of the century (1.1.2000) and reference parameters named year, month and day. The function is to calculate the current year, month and day for the given number of days passed to it. Using the references, the function should directly alter the respective actual arguments in the calling function. For this problem, assume that a year always has 365 days and every month has exactly 30 days.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void yrClac(int total, int &a, int &b, int &c);  // says incomplete type
                                                 // is not allowed

int main()
{
    int totaldays;
    cin >> totaldays;

    int year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1;
    void yrClac(totaldays, year, month, day);
    cout << year << month << day;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void yrClac(int total, int &a, int &b, int &c)
{
    a = 365 / total;
    b = total - a * 12;
    c = total - b * 30;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `void` infront of the function call inside your main.

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, it's a good idea to paste the exact error into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `void` (aka the return type) when calling the function. Remove it in `void yrClac(totaldays, year, month, day);` and it should work.

Comment: thanks for all the quick answers! 
Sorry I'm a bit of a noob.

Answer (score 3):

`void yrClac(totaldays, year, month, day);` declares a function taking objects of types `totaldays`, `year`, `month`, `day` as parameters. (None of these types have been declared, which explains the compilation error message complaining about "incomplete types").

You want to call `yrCalc`, rather than overload it, so use `yrClac(totaldays, year, month, day)` (that is, remove the `void`).

Answer (score 2):

obvious problems with your code.

Inside your `main()` you have this declaration

```
void yrClac(totaldays,year,month,day);
```

remove `void`

Another potential problem is your `365/total`
This most likely will result in `0` because of the truncation (if total is greater than 365)
You are better off either using `double` for `total` or type cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
int year=2000, month=1, day=1;

void yrClac(totaldays, year, month, day);

cout << year << month << day;
```

remove the "void" will works right. Invoking method needn't tells it which type should return.